# Returning two numbers separated by "." as number data type in JS

Tags: javascript, html, string, types, numbers

My goal is to have my JS read the following HTML as one full number instead of a string. They are separated so that the user can enter hours and minutes separately. Now I want to take the two separated numbers and turn them back into one decimal as a number instead of a string. Is this possible?

Here is my HTML:

```
 <h4>Time worked for all shifts:</h4>
  <span id="hoursTotal">0</span>.<span id="minTotal">00</span>
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `0.00` is not a "valid" number in that it will just become `0`. Likewise `2.75` would not be a "valid" input in your case since minutes are limited to 59. What are you trying to do here, exactly?

Comment: I think the decimal is a ratio of 0-59 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `parseFloat()`:

```js
var h = document.getElementById("hoursTotal").textContent;
var m = document.getElementById("minTotal").textContent;
var t = parseFloat(h+'.'+m);
console.log(`The type of ${t} is `+ typeof(t));
```

```html
<h4>Time worked for all shifts:</h4>
<span id="hoursTotal">1</span>.<span id="minTotal">01</span>
```

Comment: I tried using parseInt and divided the second number by 100 and added it to the first. Seems to have worked for now, I will try this if it stops working. Thank you